# Compare Java ClassLoader with Dynamic Load of native libraries

Tags: java, dll, classloader

I am trying to figure out what are the advantages of the Java classloader in a large multi-modules project compared to dynamic load of native libraries using the Win32 API functions LoadLibrary, GetProcAddress.

What are the impacts on deployment, versioning, sensibility to API changes using both technologies? In fact, the overall cost of maintenance.

Some related questions that I am also wondering:
- Does the classloader helps to prevent DLL hell? 
- How make it possible to implement "side by side" mode of several modules?

This is an open question. Feel free to give your opinion even if you do not have a complete answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, these are 2 mechanisms that aim for the same objective.  Dynamic library loading was designed and implemented way before JVM or .NET were conceived, and (this is a matter of my particular taste) any of teh latter do this quite more smoothly.

The DLL hell was supposed to be prevented by including version number in the name of the DLL, but you can get similar effects in java if you are careless with what you put into your classpath.

Since you have a total control on the classpath of your applications, the syde-by-side idea of Windows DLL development is perfectly feasible in java - just as always, make totally sure what you have in your classpath.  If you would like to investigate tools like maven/gradle (build automation and dependency management) and nexus (dependencies repository for java), they will help you to manage your dependencies with a lot of precision and ease.

I hope you find this useful

Comment: Thanks, it helps! You said the JVM manages dependecies more smoothly. Can you give me some concrete examples/scenarios ?

Comment: Well, as I have said, it is a matter of taste, but in my times, building a set of projects with dynamic DLL dependencies in Visual Studio 6.0 felt like making a sudoku while riding a mad tiger by its tail.  However, trying to do this in .NET or Java felt much more intuitive and easy - but I admit it could only mean a difference of ability by my part since a lot of time had past :P